# How to align the buttons on correct position in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to align the buttons as shown bellow,
[image]

for this, I used relative layout. But The buttons are not fit to correct position due to the buttons relations with others. I don't know other possible methods for this.. Please Help me if there another suitable methods for this arrangement of buttons..

Comment: Goodness it looks like Spider Space Lolz

Comment: Better you use a linear layout....with margins .... but for that you need to know the device screen dimensions, which can be found using DisplayMetrics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can design as much as u want

First of all make one

Large size Relative layout

add four buttons to that layout at each cornet of layout.

then add button to exact middle of two corner buttons

[image]
try this[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#00F" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#FFF" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button7"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I worked on your solution and made a similar looking layout. But I couldn't get exactly what you are looking for, bcoz your Image sample is some what in a square manner whereas the device screen is in rectangular shape.

Anyway try this out,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/first_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=" 1"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=" 2"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:text=" 3"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:text=" 4"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:text=" 5"/>

        <Button  android:id="@+id/button6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:text=" 6"/>

           <Button  android:id="@+id/button7"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text=" 7"/>


           <Button  android:id="@+id/button8"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:text=" 8"/>

              <RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/first_layout"
                  android:paddingTop="50dip"
                  android:paddingBottom="50dip"
                  android:paddingLeft="40dip"
                  android:paddingRight="40dip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=" 1"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=" 2"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:text=" 3"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:text=" 4"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:text=" 5"/>

        <Button  android:id="@+id/button6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:text=" 6"/>

           <Button  android:id="@+id/button7"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text=" 7"/>


           <Button  android:id="@+id/button8"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:text=" 8"/>

              <RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/first_layout"
                  android:paddingTop="50dip"
                  android:paddingBottom="50dip"
                  android:paddingLeft="40dip"
                  android:paddingRight="40dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=" 1"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=" 2"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:text=" 3"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:text=" 4"/>

     <Button  android:id="@+id/button5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:text=" 5"/>

        <Button  android:id="@+id/button6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:text=" 6"/>

           <Button  android:id="@+id/button7"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text=" 7"/>


           <Button  android:id="@+id/button8"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:text=" 8"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot,**

[image]